# Pointwise convergence of a sequence of continuous monotone functions to a continuous function is uniform?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable real-valued functions converging pointwise to a continuous function $f$. Assume further that each of the $f_n$, and $f$ itself, is a strictly monotone increasing function (note: the sequence is not necessarily monotone in $n$).

Does this imply that $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f$? And that $f_n$ is therefore equicontinuous?

Comment: You may want to check the second one of Dini's theorems. (Not the first, which is about a monotone sequence of functions; the [second](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini#Deuxi.C3.A8me_th.C3.A9or.C3.A8me_de_Dini) [Warning: link towards a French page] is on a sequence of monotone functions).

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: Quoting [this page](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=5503958): "*In their book "Regular Variation", Bingham, Goldie, and Teugels 
mention Polya's extension of this result (Polya's asserting locally 
uniform convergence when the common domain of the functions is 
(0,infinity)); see exercise 22 on page 60 of that book. They refer to 
vol. II of "Problems and Theorems in Analysis" by Polya and Szego, 
specifically problem 127 of the 1976 edition of the book.*" (I assume learning French to parse the Wikipedia reference is out of the question).

Comment: I know some French, actually. I'll look for that.

Comment: Just look for the reference at the [bottom of the page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8mes_de_Dini#cite_note-1).

Comment: I found it, thanks! I never knew French wikipedia could be so much better than the English one! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is false on $[0,1).$ Consider $f_n(x) = x + x^n,f(x) = x.$

Comment: You need compactness of the domain, IIRC, indeed.